# Should I use UltraMonkey to load balance a web server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, load-balancing

I want to load balance an Apache web server. A quick Google search on this returned a lot of old content about a Linux application called "UltraMonkey".

There seems to be a lot of people using UltraMonkey however, the latest release was in 2005 which makes me cautious about whether it is still a good solution.

http://www.ultramonkey.org/history.html

Is it recommendable to use UltraMonkey still? If so, are there any considerations I need to make? If not, what other technologies should I look into for load balancing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 2.2 the Apache web server ships a load balancer module called mod_proxy_balancer. All you need to do is to enable and configure this module.

https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/easy_http_load_balancing_with

Comment: I'm not sure why you've been voted down. Apache might not be the best solution compared with lighter weight HAProxy or Nginx, but it's viable.

Comment: @Tim Yeah apache is not lighter weight, it takes more memory but it is **established** in the industry.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it recommendable to use UltraMonkey still?

Latest release in 2005?!? No. Hell no.

> If not, what other technologies should I look into for load balancing?

Nginx and HAproxy are both very capable, modern, well-supported, and still under active development.